# Create ASC and DESC INDEX in in one index

Tags: sql, indexing, interbase, interbase-2009

I want to create an index (in Delphi/Interbase) which contained a ASC and a DESC order.

Example:

```
CREATE INDEX AMUT_DAT ON ARTIKMUT(DATUM,ARTIKEL,KODE);
```

This create DATUM and ARTIKEL ascending.

When I create it as follow:

```
CREATE DESCENDING INDEX AMUT_DAT ON ARTIKMUT(DATUM,ARTIKEL,KODE);
```

then the field DATUM is ASCENDING, but also the ARTIKEL.  I want DATUM descending and ARTIKEL ascending.

I tried:

```
CREATE INDEX AMUT_DAT ON ARTIKMUT([DATUM] DESC,[ARTIKEL] ASC,[KODE] ASC);
```

But that does not work.

How can I create such an index in Interbase?

Comment: Why do you use square brackets in the last SQL code, but not in the others!? What does not work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: The error is Token unknown - line 1, char 35.
It does not recognize the bracket.

I read about this brackets, but it does not work. The question is : How can I import an index with two or more different asc or desc. What is the right/correct syntax to create such an index. One field ASC and another DESC.

Thanks

Comment: Token unknown - line 1, char 41

It does not recognize DESC. (That why I tried the brackets)

Comment: It seems, that Interbase (and Firebird) does not support this! (I tried with the help of the tool ``SQL Manger for Interbse and Firebird``)

Comment: This is indeed not supported by Interbase. Perhaps you can achieve that with an Expression Index.

Comment: If the index is asc or desc doesn't make any differences for the database engine. Therfore it is not an option.

Comment: A fully ascending or descending index (for single or multiple columns/keys) is useful for equality matches, range retrievals, and navigational walks (supporting ORDER BY etc.).

Yes, InterBase does not support the syntax that you request; mixed asc/desc order of columns in a index definition. Can you elaborate on your use case that will be served by this, as compared to the support index definition/order?